# How can I define the number of connection points based on user input when adding a shape?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm trying to create a shape that represents an AV connection panel.
I'd like Visio to prompt the user for the number of connections when the shape is dragged from the stencil into the drawing.

In the ShapeSheet for the master I've added sections for user data and shape data, but neither of these cause a prompt to appear (such as when adding a 'grid' shape prompts for the number of rows and columns).
How do I cause the prompt to appear?
And then I assume I'll need to attach some code to this object that creates new rows in the connection points section, but I don't know where to start with this.

Apologies if this is a basic question - I'd like to get to know this program in depth but time is not on my side.

Comment: In the ShapeSheet, Shape Data, Ask field, did you set them all to True?